# Tree builder Design

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build a simple app for building a tree and I am not sure how I should go about it. Similar to :

[image]

Where you can expand and minimize a branch by clicking the node. Now my question is: Is it better to have one surface view and draw the tree to a canvas and check if appropriate areas of the screen have been touched or should each node be its own view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite broad and opinion based, but if you really what to display your tree something like in your image, it will probably be easier to go with a SurfaceView or other custom view and render the whole thing yourself.

Note - you do not need a SurfaceView, you can simply create your own custom view by deriving from View class and override the onDraw() method.